# HTML5 application for PlayBook - how to "handle" gestures?

Tags: blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

I was asked to build a playbook app using HTML5. That's the first time I'm going to work with Playbook, and I do not have any experience with it. I googled a bit, and looks like I can use WebWorks to create HTML5 application which can be deployed on Playbook. So that should not be a problem. **Here are my questions**:

1. Does that HTML5 app supports gestures (left/right swipe, multitouch, etc)?
2. If yes - how to capture them (if I'm using jQuery, for example)?
3. Are there any restrictions in gestures comparing to "native" app?
4. Can you please point me to the document/tutorial for jQuery and gesture integration with WebWorks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes, javascript. Or a library like jQuery / jqMobi, etc. Lots out there.
3. No.
4. Look at the [Kitchen Sink](https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Samples) touch/gestures sample.